# Monthly Total Calculation Using Ruby Calculations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have the calculations to tabulate the totals since the beginning of this app. I need help calculating the totals for just the current month and am not sure how to do that. Thanks in advance.

item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  def profit_calc
    sold_for - bought_for - fees - shipping rescue 0
  end

  def self.purchase_total
    sum(:bought_for)
  end

  def self.fee_total
    sum(:fees)
  end

  def self.shipping_total
    sum(:shipping)
  end

  def self.sales_total
    sum(:sold_for)
  end

  def self.profit_total
    sold.sum(:sold_for) - sold.sum(:bought_for) - sold.sum(:fees) -    sold.sum(:shipping)
  end

  def profit_margin_item
    profit_calc / sold_for * 100 rescue 0
  end

  def self.profit_margin_total
    profit_total/ sum(:sold_for) * 100
  end

  scope :visible, -> { where(sold: false) }
  scope :sold, -> { where(sold: true) }

  def self.search(search)
    where("description LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
  end
end
```

statistics.html.erb

```
<h1 id="title">Statistics</h1>
<br>

<table align="center" style="width: 95%" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Total Bought</th>
      <th>Bought This Month</th>
      <th>Total Sold</th>
      <th>Sold This Month</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><%= @items.count %></td>
      <td><%= @items_month.count %></td>
      <td><%= @items_sold.count %></td>
      <td><%= @items_sold_month.count %></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table align="center" style="width: 95%" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Total Purchases</th>
      <th>Total Month Purchases</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><%= number_to_currency(@items.purchase_total) %></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table align="center" style="width: 95%" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Total Sales</th>
      <th>Total Month Sales</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><%= number_to_currency(@items.sales_total) %></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table align="center" style="width: 95%" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Total Fees</th>
      <th>Total Month Fees</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><%= number_to_currency(@items.fee_total) %></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table align="center" style="width: 95%" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Total Shipping</th>
      <th>Total Month Shipping</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><%= number_to_currency(@items.shipping_total) %></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table align="center" style="width: 95%" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Total Profit</th>
      <th>Total Month Profit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><%= number_to_currency(@items.profit_total) %></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table align="center" style="width: 95%" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Total Margin</th>
      <th>Total Month Margin</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><%= number_to_percentage(@items.profit_margin_total, precision: 0) %></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following condition to get the calculation for current month:

```
where(created_at: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month..Time.zone.now.end_of_month)
```

For example:

```
def self.purchase_total
  where(created_at: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month..Time.zone.now.end_of_month).sum(:bought_for)
end
```

If you're going to use it extensively, add it as a [`scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope):

```
scope :current_month, -> { where(created_at: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month..Time.zone.now.end_of_month) }
```

Now:

```
def self.purchase_total
  current_month.sum(:bought_for)
end
```

Comment: That works great. Thanks for your help and Happy Thanksgiving!

Comment: @MikeWiesenhart you're welcome and Happy Thanksgiving :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko What about for profit_total and profit_margin_total since those are calculations and not pulling from the sum of the DB contents.

Comment: @MikeWiesenhart `def self.profit_total
  sold.current_month.sum(:sold_for) - sold.current_month.sum(:bought_for) - sold.current_month.sum(:fees) - sold.current_month.sum(:shipping)
end` - `profit_margin_total` stays unchanged :)